# Is it possible to efficiently search a column with non-decreasing values without an index?

Tags: mysql, database, performance, indexing

I am creating a table that will contain a very large (100M+) set of history records. Each record is time-stamped and is guaranteed to never change.

The main read operations will be queries for all records between specific dates/date-times, which will mostly result in a tiny subset of the total records - a time span of a few days and normally from specific controllers.

Since data are written sequentially, the time stamps are **guaranteed** to be non-decreasing.

```sql
CREATE TABLE history
(
  id            INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  controller_id INT(11) UNSIGNED,
  node_address  SMALLINT UNSIGNED,
  p1            SMALLINT,
  p2            SMALLINT,
  state         BOOL,
  created       DATETIME
)
  ENGINE = InnoDB
  DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8;
```

For the sake of simplicity, we can ignore the other constraints and assume that a typical query will be something like:

```
SELECT * FROM `history` WHERE `created` BETWEEN <date_time_1> AND <date_time_2>
```

Creating an index will be costly in space and will likely decrease insertion performance, but without it, a full table scan may be performed, making it an O(n) operation, whereas in reality, an O(log(n)) would be sufficient, given the constraints on data, via a binary search.

Is there a way to hint MySQL (or, for the matter, other database engines), to treat the monotonically increasing field as such and perform fast lookup, without using an index?

Is there a better approach for achieving this?

**Clarification:**

Although creating an index is entirely possible and I probably will use it if I have to, finding an efficient alternative method that avoids it is the topic of the question. Hopefully, a method that doesn't involve significant extra maintenance or storage overhead.

Therefore, this question was mainly created out of curiosity, in hope that someone came across a similar scenario and came up with something to avoid creating the index.

Comment: Don't try to outsmart standard techniques.  Also, stop and think again about the implications of what you are asking...  If the inserted values are indeed monotonic, then insert performance issues from having this index in place would be almost non-existent, would they not?

Comment: I agree that theoretically the performance hit on inserts should be negligible, but I fear that this is overly optimistic. I believe that the large enough portion of the tree has to bee in memory in order for the implications to be nonexistent, but as the index becomes larger, I suspect that it won't fit into available memory and will be swapped, thus inducing cache misses that will hinder performance. That is why I was looking for a way to accomplish such hinting. I guess that it's a long shot, but still worth asking.

Comment: Spoiler alert :) I can think of no such mechanism.  But unless you need the auto-incrementing "id" column, you could perhaps make (created,controller_address,node_id) the primary key, instead, since that's always the clustered index anyway in InnoDB... the first one is free... but ultimately I think you are prematurely optimizing a problem that's mostly theoretical, *particularly* when you're inserting in index order and never modifying.  Let's see if someone chimes in with an answer we didn't think of.

Comment: Thanks. I hope so, too, and I will take the compound primary key clustered index into consideration :)

Comment: The key issue here is that records in a table are not an ordered structure while an index is. Arithmetic operations performed upon ordered structures are cheap and we can find the record we need in a few I/Os. A table is *not an ordered structure*. Sure, it's written in a sequence, but if you want to find a record that equals something or between something, you have to go through entire table to find it because you don't know what possible values you have to compare. An index trades space for speed and allows for these operations. Answer is - no, you can't.

Comment: I know that a table is generally not an ordered structure, but this particular column is, as I mentioned in the question. This is exactly the question here - can anything be done to utilize this property without using an index. That is, provided that I have an O(1) "random access" time to the k-th record when k is known.

Comment: The only order that exists here is that every next record contains a larger timestamp. That's not sufficient for efficient comparison and you can't effectively use that for anything - it's not ordered by value that's available in an ordered structure, any database would have to perform full table scan. I can tell what you're after, but sadly you can't do anything about it without an index.

Answer (score 1):

"between specific dates" -- Do you mean DATEs?  Or DATETIMEs?

If **DATEs**, then build a lookup table mapping DATE to INT, and make one pass over the huge table to populate this lookup table.  Then use that table in any SELECT to change the given DATE(s) into the desired INT(s).  Be sure to pick the id for the *first* of each occurrence of a DATE.

If **DATETIMEs**, then do something similar.  This time map every, say, 1000th row's DATETIME to INT.  Now the WHERE clause will need to be generous (`<=` instead of `<`, or whatever) to avoid the cases where there are multiple rows with the same second and you landed in the middle of the set.

(The end-cases are a nuisance; I alluded to some of them.  Some variation might be simpler.)

If you are doing SUM and COUNT over date (or hour) ranges, you should regularly build another day's (or hour's) worth of summaries.  Put them into a **Summary Table**.  Then the queries will be much faster.

Doing things over, here is the **cheapest** way to build the table:

```
PRIMARY KEY(created, id)  -- clustered, giving you the index you really want
INDEX(id)  -- sufficient to make AUTO_INCREMENT happy
```

There is no extra cost in the data.  There is the cost of the secondary index (perhaps 3GB).  INSERTs will be only slightly slower because of the "hot spot" already mentioned.

Even better...  Sure, if (created, controller_address, node_id) is **unique** then use that as the PK and completely get rid of `id`.  This saves 4 bytes in the data; no change in index; no change in INSERT.

See **pt-online-schema-change** for how to make the change with virtually no impact.  (It does require a TRIGGER and enough disk space for an extra copy of the table.)

Also, keep in mind that you are 1/40th of the way to **overflowing** `INT UNSIGNED`.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. Actually, a LUT with an entry for each day (could be dine during the first batch read after midnight) may work. However, this incurs overhead in the logic required for each query and for maintaining the LUT (we will also be batch deleting old records). The purpose of the question is partly academic; to somehow exploit the non-decreasing attribute of the column for efficiency, without indexing. Therefore, I will keep this one open for now.